# NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, beancreationexception

I am getting the below exception when I am trying to configure my GAE Web Project using Springs MVC. I have used the following configurations in my files. I am using spring-3.2.3 version of Springs and I have **spring-bean-3.2.3.jar** in my classpath already.

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myweb.webservices" />

    <bean id="cnManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true"/>
        <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
        <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html" />
        <property name="useJaf" value="false"/>

        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
                <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven content-negotiation-manager="cnManager"/>

    <bean class="com.myweb.webservices.spring.MvcConfiguringPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myweb.webservices."/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myweb.webservices.dao"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myweb.webservices.service"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myweb.webservices.controller"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
      p:prefix="/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />
</beans>
```

**GenericDao.java**

```
public interface GenericDao {
    public <T> void create(T t);
}
```

**AbstractGenericDaoImpl.java**

```
public abstract class AbstractGenericDaoImpl implements GenericDao{

    static {
        ObjectifyService.register(User.class);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> void create(T t) {
        ofy().save().entity(t).now();
    }
}
```

**GenericService.java**

```
public interface GenericService {
    public <T> void create(T t);
}
```

**AbstractGenericServiceImpl.java**

```
public abstract class AbstractGenericServiceImpl implements GenericService{

    @Autowired
    GenericDao genericDao;

    @Override
    public <T> void create(T t) {
        genericDao.create(t);
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'authenticationFilter' while setting constructor argument with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authenticationFilter' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'customAuthenticationManager' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuthenticationManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myweb.webservices.service.UserService com.myweb.webservices.authentication.CustomAuthenticationManager.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.myweb.webservices.common.dao.GenericDao com.myweb.webservices.common.dao.AbstractGenericServiceImpl.genericDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.myweb.webservices.common.dao.GenericDao] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: testDao,userDao
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:249)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:307)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.java:26)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer.startup(AbstractServer.java:80)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Servers.startup(Servers.java:82)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:237)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:339)
at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:274)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:250)
```

Answer (score 4):

The error is

```
No qualifying bean of type [com.myweb.webservices.common.dao.GenericDao] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: testDao,userDao
```

Somewhere in one of your packages that are component scanned, you are creating both a `UserDao` and a `TestDao`. Since they are both implementations of `GenericDao`, they are clashing for which one will be used as an `@Autowired` target. I believe you should get rid of your `TestDao` in this context.

---

Without seeing the rest of your configuration, this in your root context

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myweb.webservices" />
```

and this in the servlet context

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myweb.webservices."/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myweb.webservices.dao"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myweb.webservices.service"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myweb.webservices.controller"/>
```

will create duplicate beans which will most likely cause more problems. Make your component scans as specific as possible. Component scanning is recursive through packages.

---

This bean

```
<bean id="cnManager" class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
...
```

is relevant only to your servlet. It should be in the servlet context, not the root context.

---

In your servlet context, don't forget to enable

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Comment: Sir I have a GenericDao, GenricService and its implementation and they are implemented by UserDao, TestDao. I need to make a Generic Model so that the later can use the methods from Generic Interface and classes.

Comment: @ankur This `@Autowired GenericDao genericDao;` in your `AbstractGenericServiceImpl` class won't work because Spring finds two candidates for it and can't choose which one. Rethink your design or specify which bean specifically with the `@Qualified` annotation.

Comment: Sir I have removed **@Autowired** from GenericDao and the exception is away. But can you guide me how can I access the DAO layer using Service Layer without using **@Autowired** Annotation.

Comment: @AnkurJain You should use `@Autowired` in your `@Service` classes by specifying the specific type. If you need a `UserDao`, autowire a `UserDao`, not a `GenericDao`.

Comment: Sir, I am already using `@Repository` in my UserDaoImpl and `@Service` in UserServiceImpl but this also not working for me. Moreover I need to have a GenericTemplated Service and DAO layer which I can implement in the futher Entity DAOs and Services.

Comment: @Ankur You're not following. In your class that will extend from `AbstractGenericServiceImpl`, maybe a `UserServiceImpl`, put an `@Autowired private UserDao userDao;` field. Same for the other implementation classes.